# Stream audio from Kotlin/Spring back-end to front-end

Tags: javascript, java, spring, audio, kotlin

#### The idea of the project I'm doing is:

- N users join a "room" (through the web browser)
- The Java backend controls which song will play in the frontend
- Everyone in the room listens to the song at the same time. Like a live audio stream
- If someone joins later, it will listen the song at the same point the others are listening.

---

#### The questions are:

> I) So far, I'm able to send the mp3 bytes from the java backend to the frontend when the JS does a GET. But it always plays the song from the beginning when it downloads. How can I make the js download a chunk and play it as it uis downloaded?
>
> II) If that's not the best way to keep the same audio time flowing, how can I make everyone who GETs my Backend API receive the same audio bytes at that same time?
>
> III) How can I ensure an user that joined later on, to listen to the same audio?
>
> IV) Is RESTful API the best choice I get? Would WebSockets be a better choice? So far, the REST approach with that "constant flowing bytes GET" seemed good.

---

#### So far, I have:

A Kotlin with spring-reactor backend whose GET mapping returns a Flux and writes the audio bytes in the HttpServletResponse (not 100% reactive, I know).
My JS downloads the entire byte first and then plays it for whoever downloaded it.

As I've never used such things as media streaming, I'm not sure what frameworks I can use to help me play the SAME audio at the SAME TIME for all users in the room.

My controller code so far:

```
@RestController
class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(path = ["/"], produces = [TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
    fun streamAudioBytes(response: HttpServletResponse): Flux<String> {

        val out = response.outputStream

        val fileIn = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:tetris-mp3.mp3")

        val bytes = fileIn.readBytes()

        return Flux.create {
            out.write(bytes)
        }
    }
}
```

My first try at playing the audio:

```
<button id="but" onclick="play();">Clica</button>
<audio id="music" preload="all">
    <source src="http://localhost:8080/">
</audio>
```

## EDIT1:

I got to "stream" the bytes from the back to the frontend, now my deal is:
My Javascript receives N bytes of the MP3 file at every T milliseconds and play them as they come, so as N bytes are received, they are played. I looked for a "buffer" approach for JS, but depending on how it works, I lose the synchronization of everyone who is receiving the bytes from the backend.

> What can I do to avoid letting the Audio be cut or be played over itself (2 buffered incomes playing at the same time)?
>   JS Code that receives the incoming bytes from backend:

```
function fetchBytes() {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/").then(response => {
        var reader = response.body.getReader();
        var bytesReceived = 0;

        // read() returns a promise that resolves
        // when a value has been received
        return reader.read().then(function processResult(result) {
            if (result.done) {
                console.log("Fetch complete");
                return;
            }

            playByteArray(result.value)
            bytesReceived += result.value.length;
            console.log('Received', bytesReceived, 'bytes of data so far');

            // Read some more, and call this function again
            return reader.read().then(processResult);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It might be worth looking into [HLS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) or [MPEG-DASH](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP). Both use http requests of chunked media files to achieve something like a live stream.